# fast cumulative operation in python?

Tags: python

I have several operators f(a, b) like: "a*2+b*3", "a^b" ...

I would like to do something like:

```
a = a0
for _b in X:
    a = f(a, _b)
```

a0 will be N-byte value, X will be M*N byte buffer. In most case N <4, and a will not overflow. python reduce() will do the job, but for custom function it seems slow.

Can numexpr or other package speed up this?

Comment: Have you tried those options by yourself? You should provide a minimal working example, you will get more attention and answers

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

1. You may want to try `functools.reduce` solution on `PyPy` (just `reduce` if you're on Python 2). In addition you can use [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/array.html) instead of `list`.
2. Use [`numpy.ufunc.reduce`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) if your lists are big enough. It is written in `C/Cython`, but it takes longer to create small numpy array than a python stdlib's collection of the same size.

Update:

3. Use Cython to implement `f(a, b)`, `reduce` or both.

Pros: you can achieve almost C performance when it comes to dealing with numbers. You don't have to know Python C API.

Cons: almost C performance comes with writing almost C code. Use pointers, do some `malloc`, declare types explicitly, get a compatible C compiler. Before starting I would suggest to use `cprofile` in order to determine the critical code.

Comment: the slow part is actually the f(a, b). If numexpr cannot do reduce, then scipy.weave or cython may be the choice?

Comment: @Wang I've worked with Cython only, so updated the answer accordingly.